# Mensa Romania IQ test question - diagonal, vertical, horizontal lines combined

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

[image]

Please help with that Mensa Romania IQ test question. I think it's B, but why?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I see you've credited Mensa Romania - could you provide a link or other sourcing information?

Comment: "I think it's B, but why?" Only _you_ know why you think it's B.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is

> E

because

> The third column shows the lines that are different between the first two columns. That is, if a line segment appears in both the first two columns, then it will not appear in the third; likewise if a line segment appears in *neither* of the first two columns it will not appear in the third. However any line segment that appears in exactly one of the first two columns will be present in the third column.
>  In a computer-science context, you might say that the columns are related by exclusive-or (XOR) - applying that operation to any two columns will yield the other.

Comment: And the same is true for rows.

Comment: Good point - once I saw the pattern I mentioned, I stopped looking

Answer (score -1):

The answer is the letter E Using a simpler example so you can easily understand, look at this image:[image]

(forgive me for my English and the quality of the image because I did it by hand on my cell phone).

basically if a line in the 1st square is in the same position as the line in the 2nd square, it cancels itself out in the 3rd square, if the lines are not repeated they will appear in the 3rd square. If a line appears in the 1st square and nothing appears in the 2nd square or vice versa, the figure will only appear in the 3rd square. Using this same logic in your question, the letter E should be the correct answer.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please be aware that this is an English-language site, so answers are expected to be provided in English. We cannot rely on Google Translate or user translations as they may not be entirely accurate. Would you be able to translate this into English for us?

Comment: Ah sorry, a Google translation should do the trick? because my English is horrible... :v

Comment: That should do, thank you.